# How to use Python 3 in Spyder 3?

Tags: 16.04, python3, spyder

I had Spyder2 running Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04. I installed Spyder3 via

```
sudo apt-get install spyder3
```

but `Spyder3` is also running Python 2.7.

I even upgraded `spyder` via `pip`

```
sudo pip install spyder --upgrade
```

but still Spyder3 is based on Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to get it aught to have been:

```
sudo pip3 install spyder
```

And see this:

```
sudo apt install spyder3
```

also works. Perhaps you need to uninstall spyder2, then install spyder3

[image]

Comment: no, I was installing `pip3` and then `pip3 install spyder`. Still, Spyder3 is running Python 2.7. I will uninstall Spyder2.

Comment: Please run `which python3`

Comment: /usr/bin/python3

Comment: I uninstalled both Spyder and Spyder3 via `apt-get` and installed via `pip3` but still, the python is 2.7.

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt purge spyder`? Use this to purge all former configurations.

Answer (score 0):

In 16.04,`spyder` is spyder 2.3.8 for **python 2** and `spyder3` is spyder 2.3.8 for **python 3** ([source](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=spyder)). In Zesty the package sources have Spyder 3.1.3, you can [download](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/spyder) and try to install it manually. From Zesty on, the package names will be less confusing here: `python-spyder` for spyder for python 2 and `python3-spyder` for spyder for python 3. However, no release has different versions of spyder in the package sources.